# Dynamic column for Percentile function in Excel

Tags: excel, function, percentile

I have a data set with many columns. I need to calculate percentiles for each one of the column into a template that is arranged in a way that if cannot just copy over the formula. Is there a way to make the column from which I calculate the percentile dynamic?
See the table below for a simplified example. What I am trying to achieve is a formula that would look something like this: `=percentile.inc(column array with name in $A11,0.25)`

This formula would be written into cell B11 and it will calculate 25th percentile of **payment** column. When I copy this formula to B12 it will automatically calculate percentile of **distance**.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using INDEX/MATCH:

```
=PERCENTILE.INC(INDEX($B$2:$C$7,,MATCH(A11,$B$1:$C$1,0)),0.25)
```

[image]